# error on running "scrapy crawl quotes" and "scrapy genspider quotes qoutes.toscrape.com" command

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I followed the tutorial to make a web scraper.

**Overview**:-

1. created virtal environment(`virtualenv .`)
2. activated it (`.\Scripts\activate`)
3. dir where scrapy.cfg lies(`cd quotetutorial`)
4. created quotes_spider.py
5. executed `scrapy crawl quotes` and `scrapy genspider quotes quotes.toscrape.com` and getting same error

spider_quotes.py file content:-

```
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):#inheriting from class scrapy from spider
    name='quotes'
    start_urls=['https://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    def parse(self,response)
        title=response.css('title').extract()
        yield {'titletext': title}
```

even after running the scrapy crawl quotes in the folder which contained the scrapy.cfg file, I am getting this error.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAu1j.png)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `:` symbol in method definition:

```
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):#inheriting from class scrapy from spider
    name='quotes'
    start_urls=['https://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    def parse(self,response): # <- : added
        title=response.css('title').extract()
        yield {'titletext': title}
```